# Modify xml file with extra namespace

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to modify an existing xml file.
The layout of the existing file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> 
 <Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
```

After i modified a field in the xml i want to get the new xml file, but the modified file is different from the original.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
```

Whats the difference between the files:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" //this is missing in the mutated file
```

So what i did:

```
ET.register_namespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
ET.register_namespace('', "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")

#parse the data
tree = ET.parse(self.sepa_xml.path)
root = tree.getroot()

#add a subelement
body = ET.SubElement(root, "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}")
```

The finale result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId>20220929085842-36645</PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
        <CtgyPurp>
          <Cd>SALA</Cd>
        </CtgyPurp>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <ReqdExctnDt>2022-09-29</ReqdExctnDt>
      <Dbtr>
        <Nm>test name</Nm>
      </Dbtr>
      </DbtrAgt>
      <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
      <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <PmtId>
          <EndToEndId>20220929085842-36645/1</EndToEndId>
        </PmtId>
      </CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
<xsi: /></Document>. // how can i delete this xsi tag ?
```

The problem is now that is get an extra tag at the end of the xml file:
<xsi:  />. I assume this is because i added a subelement. How can ik delete this last tag ?

Comment: Comment `ET.SubElement...` line out

Comment: If that line is commented out, `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` also disappears. ElementTree removes declarations for namespaces that are not actually used.

Comment: tx, i get that but i need xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in the root, otherwise the bank is rejecting this xml file. What i dont need is that last tag <xsi:

Comment: I suggest using lxml instead of ElementTree. lxml does not remove declarations for unused namespaces.

Comment: hmm yeah i looked at that, but then i have to rewrite my mutation of the xml fields.

Comment: Tx guys for the help, i rewrote the mutation of the xml file and used lxml. Couldnt find an answer with ET.